# Is it possible to link dylib without header file?

Tags: c++, macos, dylib

I'm working on Mac OS and using CLion/Xcode IDEs. I've already read a lot of information about dynamic libraries.  Is it possible to link my dylib to the project without writing "include "name_file.h"" on my Macbook? I know if it is possible in Visual Studio on Windows.  VS on Mac OS doesn't support C++.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299022). Why don't you want to include a header file? Also, you say you're using CLion, Xcode and Visual Studio - which of these is it now?

Comment: Header files just provide prototypes to the implementation found in the dylib. The prototype simply tells the compiler how to set up the stack/return value for the function call. BUt if you're using functions from a dylib why wouldn't you include the header? You absolutely should include the header.

Comment: It's my university task. so my teacher wants me to link dylib without the header. I know how to do it using VS. But I can only use Clion or Xcode

Comment: I mean of course I have to create the header. But how I can avoid writing #include "name_file.h" in my main code

Answer (score 0):

To link a library in XCode, left click the project name in the source panel to the left. At the top click the "Build Phase" tab. You will see a drop down "Link Binary with Library" click the drop down then hit the "+" symbol and locate the dylib. Then compile your code.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. But how I can use functions from my lib?

Comment: Or create the prototype to the function you are going to call, in your c file. Which is no different than just including the header file.